# I'm trying to switch out divs with jquery but Div2, which im replacing with Div1, is already visible on screen. How do I fix this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I essentially want "AboutP2" to be hidden before I click the button and then replace "AboutP1". I know that it is missing some jQuery, but I have no idea what to type. Thanks for the help!

When I run it in my browser AboutP2 is already on screen (which makes sense since its in the code) but I dont want it there.

HTML:

```
<div class="AboutP1">
        <div class="TitleAbout">
            <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, summo moderatius posidonium sea id. Duo sadipscing complectitur ea, et mazim legimus veritus ius, ne vel aliquip vivendo suscipiantur. Diam nostro feugiat ne pri, error sententiae disputationi ex vel. Quis alii audiam cu est. Per choro legere ut, ea clita euripidis efficiendi has. Eam in noluisse mediocrem. </p>
        </div>
            <div>
                <button> > Continue </button>
            </div>
</div>

<div class="AboutP2">
        <div class="MoreAbout">
            <p> Idque hendrerit vim at, accumsan vivendum verterem eu qui. Facer nusquam ne ius, nam eros nobis sadipscing ei. Choro vitae vivendum mel eu. Eius volumus at mea, te per tibique rationibus, tantas delicatissimi pri ad. Eu mel inani ignota assueverit, nec audiam minimum accumsan ne, per cu velit clita utamur.</p>
        </div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(function() {

    $('button').click(function() {
        $('div.AboutP1').replaceWith('AboutP2');

    });

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to show and hide the content. This is the typical way of display data with jQuery. You put a class on the element that you want hidden at the start and then you can toggle. That class on and off to display/hide it.

```js
$('button').on('click', function(){
  $('.AboutP1').addClass('hidden');
  $('.AboutP2').removeClass('hidden');
})
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="AboutP1">
        <div class="TitleAbout">
            <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, summo moderatius posidonium sea id. Duo sadipscing complectitur ea, et mazim legimus veritus ius, ne vel aliquip vivendo suscipiantur. Diam nostro feugiat ne pri, error sententiae disputationi ex vel. Quis alii audiam cu est. Per choro legere ut, ea clita euripidis efficiendi has. Eam in noluisse mediocrem. </p>
        </div>
            <div>
                <button> > Continue </button>
            </div>
</div>

<div class="AboutP2 hidden">
        <div class="MoreAbout">
            <p> Idque hendrerit vim at, accumsan vivendum verterem eu qui. Facer nusquam ne ius, nam eros nobis sadipscing ei. Choro vitae vivendum mel eu. Eius volumus at mea, te per tibique rationibus, tantas delicatissimi pri ad. Eu mel inani ignota assueverit, nec audiam minimum accumsan ne, per cu velit clita utamur.</p>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I've been looking online for 4 hours and couldn't find anything. Thank you again!

Comment: No problem! Yeah sometimes you just don't know what you need to look for.  Good luck and don't be afraid to ask tons of questions!